# how to filter blank image product collection by observer

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

I need to filter collection for product listing.
I know how to re-write block.
But i want to filter that collection by observer.

basically i want to do this by observer...

this the code for filter blank image.

```
->addAttributeToFilter('image', 'no_selection');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read how to use observers in the official wiki - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method .

For your case please try to use this:
in config.xml

```
<events>
    <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
        <observers>
            <filter_blank_image>
                <class>modulename/observer</class>
                <method>filterBlankImage</method>
            </filter_blank_image>
        </observers>
    </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
</events>
```

in Observer.php

```
public function filterBlankImage(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('image', 'no_selection');
    return $this;
}
```