# How to filter blank product image from catalogsearch and catalog in magento via observer

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, catalog, catalogsearch

I need to filter blank image product in Magento from catalog and catalogsearch.
But it working fine on catalog. bt not fine in catalog search.

I got error when search product in search....

```
  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.small_image' in 'where clause'"
```

### config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nine_Catalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Nine_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
                <observers>
                    <filter_blank_image> // unique idrntifer
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Nine_Catalog_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>filterBlankImage</method>
                    </filter_blank_image>
                </observers>
            </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

### Observer.php

```
class Nine_Catalog_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{

    public function filterBlankImage(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        return  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('small_image',array('neq'=>'no_selection'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enable `catalog product flat setting` then  may be `small_image` column 
is not created at `catalog_product_flat_YourStoreId` table.So please reindex  `catalog product` from `admin Index Management`.

If `small_image column` is not create then add below code to `config. xml` for  enable this attribute to flat.

```
<frontend>
    <product>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                <small_image/>
                <small_image_label/>
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </product>
</frontend>
```

**Code Observer code:**

```
<?php
class Nine_Catalog_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer{

    public function filterBlankImage(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('small_image',array('notnull'=>'','neq'=>'no_selection'));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**If this not work then must issue with indexing**
See at another example [how to filter blank image product collection by observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48979/how-to-filter-blank-image-product-collection-by-observer)